# Cannot Open Jupyter notebook in Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, dllimport

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\laylasun\Anaconda2\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 3, in 
import notebook.notebookapp
File "C:\Users\laylasun\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 39, in 
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File "C:\Users\laylasun\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\laylasun\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\laylasun\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\laylasun\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 26, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\laylasun\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

---

System info:
System information

```
platform: win-64
version: 1.6.2
conda: 4.3.21
qt: 5.6.2
language: en_US
python: 2.7.13
os: Windows;10;10.0.14393;AMD64;Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
pyqt: 5.6.0
```

---

I have completely uninstalled python27 and reinstalled Anaconda2 for win64. But the problem is still there.